# How to restart redis and celery from scratch?

Tags: ubuntu, redis, celery, supervisord

I'm using Celery with Redis broker on my Digital Ocean VPS. I'm new in Celery and Ubuntu so maybe there is a simple solution.

I changed one of my Django tasks and it looked like Celery uses the old version. So I tried to restart redis and celery using `redis-server shutdown` and kill `celery` process.

The problem is that now, nothing works. It seems to be freezing when I run either `redis-cli` or when I try to check celery status (there is running supervisord).

[image]

[image]

As you can see, both commands aren't responding.

What should I do? I'm considering restarting a VPS but I'm not sure if it doesn't do any harm.

Comment: You can see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9772030/747017) for restarting celery.

Answer (score 0):

redis-cli is a command line client for redis, which can't connect to redis when the server is shut down.