# How to restart celery worker gracefully to not impact running agents?

Tags: python, celery, celery-task, celeryd

I'm running a celery worker as a `systemd` daemon which serves a lot of long-running agents.

When I restart the worker all the agents hang and stop running new tasks waiting for pending ones.

- Restarting agents is not an acceptable solution for me.
- I'd also avoid using task timeouts

Is there a way to restart the worker gracefully to not impact already running agents?

All the agents are `python` scripts.

Comment: might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9764913/how-do-i-restart-celery-workers-gracefully, specifically the answer regarding stopping workers with the `HUP` signal

Comment: @Jason That's exactly how I do restart the workers.

Comment: via `ps auxww | grep celeryd | grep -v "grep" | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -HUP`?  Apparently your desire isn't all that possible to do in celery.

Comment: @Jason Nope, I use `celery multi restart|stopwait`. Why do you say it's not possible?