# How can I automatically reload tasks modules with Celery daemon?

Tags: python, celery

I am using Fabric to deploy a Celery broker (running RabbitMQ) and multiple Celery workers with `celeryd` daemonized through `supervisor`. I cannot for the life of me figure out how to reload the `tasks.py` module short of rebooting the servers.

---

**/etc/supervisor/conf.d/celeryd.conf**

```
[program:celeryd]
directory=/fab-mrv/celeryd
environment=[RABBITMQ crendentials here]
command=xvfb-run celeryd --loglevel=INFO --autoreload
autostart=true
autorestart=true
```

---

**celeryconfig.py**

```
import os

## Broker settings
BROKER_URL = "amqp://%s:%s@hostname" % (os.environ["RMQU"], os.environ["RMQP"])

# List of modules to import when celery starts.
CELERY_IMPORTS = ("tasks", )

## Using the database to store task state and results.
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "amqp"

CELERYD_POOL_RESTARTS = True
```

---

**Additional information**

- `celery --version` 3.0.19 (Chiastic Slide)
- `python --version`  2.7.3
- `lsb_release -a` Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS
- `rabbitmqctl status` ... 2.7.1 ...

---

**Here are some things I have tried:**

- The `celeryd --autoreload` flag
- `sudo supervisorctl restart celeryd`
- `celery.control.broadcast('pool_restart', arguments={'reload': True})`
- `ps auxww | grep celeryd | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -HUP`

And unfortunately, nothing causes the workers to reload the tasks.py module (e.g. after running `git pull` to update the file).  **The gist of the relevant fab functions is available [here](https://gist.github.com/pztrick/5713866).**

The brokers/workers run fine after a reboot.

Comment: `supervisorctl restart` usually does the trick for me.

Comment: Alas, not for me. I have added a gist for my `fabfile.py` with the relevant fab functions excerpted.

Comment: wide guess here, but have you tried to delete `*.pyc` before reloading?

Comment: Have you tried the [reload](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reload) function?

Comment: I usually just sudo into supervisorctl and then do `restart <celery_conf>`. as @PauloScardine mentioned, you may want to clear old *.pyc files as these can cause an issue from time to time.

Comment: Deleting the *.pyc files, in combination with the usual `supevisorctl` commands, the `-HUP` kill signal, or `celery.control.broadcast` did not work. I now **have it working** by sending a `-9` kill signal to **both** `celeryd` and `Xvfb` so it seems to be related to the headless X server process. A `-9` signal isn't exactly graceful, but nothing else is working.

Comment: @pztrick: I'm curious, why do you need X?

Comment: I'm using Selenium on my worker nodes and need Xvfb to emulate Firefox (since they have no GUI)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9642669/how-to-restart-celery-gracefully-without-delaying-tasks

Comment: Have you tried to restart RabbitMQ also?

Answer (score 3):

I faced a similar problem and was able to use [Watchdog](https://github.com/gorakhargosh/watchdog) to reload the `tasks.py` tasks modules when there are changes detected. To install:

```
pip install watchdog
```

You can programmatically use the Watchdog API, for example, to monitor for directory changes in the file system. Additionally Watchdog provides an optional shell utility called `watchmedo` that can be used to execute commands on event. Here is an example that starts the Celery worker via Watchdog and reloads on any changes to `.py` files including changes via `git pull`:

```
watchmedo auto-restart --directory=./ --pattern="*.py" --recursive -- celery worker --app=worker.app --concurrency=1 --loglevel=INFO
```

Using Watchdog's `watchmedo` I was able to `git pull` changes and the respective `tasks.py` modules were auto reloaded without any reboot of the container or server.

Answer (score 2):

Just a shot in the dark, with the `celeryd --autoreload` option did you make sure you have one of the [file system notification backends](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/master/userguide/workers.html#autoreloading)? It recommends PyNotify for linux, so I'd start by making sure you have that installed.

Comment: No dice. :( `Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pyinotify in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` **(Version 0.9.4)**