# Celery autoreload not working

Tags: python, django, celery, celerybeat, pyinotify

I am using Celery 3.1.16 broker (running RabbitMQ) and multiple Celery workers with celeryd daemonized through supervisor. Problem is with tasks update. When I update my tasks.py file, celery worker runs old code.

Celery launch command:

```
/home/my_project/bin/celery -B --autoreload --app=my_app.celery:app worker --loglevel=INFO
```

I include tasks file in django settings.py:

```
CELERY_IMPORTS = [
    'my_app.tasks'
]
```

**pyinotify** is installed and works (I guess so), part of celery logs:

```
[2014-12-16 20:56:00,016: INFO/MainProcess] Task my_app.tasks.periodic_update_task_statistic[175c2557-7c07-43c3-ac70-f4e115344134] succeeded in 0.00816309102811s: 'ok!'
[2014-12-16 20:56:11,157: INFO/MainProcess] Detected modified modules: ['my_app.tasks']
[2014-12-16 20:57:00,001: INFO/Beat] Scheduler: Sending due task my_app.tasks.periodic_update_task_statistic (my_app.tasks.periodic_update_task_statistic)
[2014-12-16 20:57:00,007: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: my_app.tasks.periodic_update_task_statistic[f22998a9-dcb4-4c29-8086-86dd6e57eae1]
```

So, my question: **how to get celery update and apply new tasks code, if they were modified?**

Comment: I don't have an answer. I still just reboot my workers when I do a code push. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16929264/how-can-i-automatically-reload-tasks-modules-with-celery-daemon

Comment: Same here. I restart celery at the end of the deployment procedure. Deployment is done using fabric for that matters.

Comment: Hi LJ, any updates on this question? Were you able to figure out?

Comment: I use supervisor in docker for local development and I also can't find out how to make --autoreload work.

Answer (score 2):

Celery has open issue with this problem
https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/1025

Answer (score 1):

I have this same problem. While I don't like it, I do the following, which first removes and compiled .pyc files anywhere under my current directory, then restarts all the workers.

`find . -name "*.pyc" -exec rm {} \;
supervisorctl restart all`

It seems strange that the `--autoreload` flag does nothing, but it doesn't in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Celery only autoreloads those modules that it directly loaded, it does not keep an eye on other modules that loaded by the direct modules.